# Finding the images of a two linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The problem is as follows:
[image]

Work was as follows:
[image]

Following our examples of transformations in class as largely a sort of matrix multiplication.

WebWork says both answers are incorrect, however.

Comment: First off, you need to multiply them in the correct order.  The matrix A should be on the left and the vector should be on the right because that is how T is defined.  Multiplying them the other way is not even possible because the inner dimensions do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to perform matrix multiplication:
$$
T(v) = A v
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 5 \\
-1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a  \\
b
\end{pmatrix}
=
a
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
+
b
\begin{pmatrix}
5 \\
-2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dotsb  \\
\dotsb
\end{pmatrix}
$$